# How to distribute my work on Microsoft Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, tkinter

Alright so I have for my school projected created a python tkinter game on Microsoft Visual Studio Code but in order to submit my work, I need to submit it to my teacher like an application where my 'users' can simply download my project say off github etc and should be able to open up instantly without them having to use my code and running it like this. Im not too sure if this makes sense or not. I have tired to google it but I can't find out how to make it into this sort of way for simple access into my application.

I have tried to google it, and use profiles however that didn't work. I'm not too sure what I need to do here.

Answer (score -1):

Use PyInstaller to pack your code to one application including the dependences. then others can run it directly without python and packages.